# Ant build symlink error

Tags: ant, jakarta-ee, java

I am getting the symlink error when i do an ant build.  Searched in net and some posts  suggested to download junit jar for fixing it. Downloaded  junit-4.8.2.jar.  Added  this jar file to Classpath but still's not working.  I tried to include the jar file within the build.xml but still it didn't work out.

```
<target name="-createDir" description="Creates logs directory">
    <mkdir dir="${basedir}/${custServer}/logs" />
    <symlink link="${basedir}/${custS}/application.properties" resource="${basedir}/application.properties" />
    <symlink link="${basedir}/${custS}/log4j.properties" resource="${basedir}/log4j.properties" />
</target>
```

-createDir:

BUILD FAILED
file:/home/test1/source/teff/build.xml:28: Could not create task or type of type: symlink.

Ant could not find the task or a class this task relies upon.

ant -v
Apache Ant version 1.5.4 compiled on January 8 2005
Buildfile: build.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `symlink` task was introduced in `ant` version [1.6.0](http://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/RELEASE-NOTES-1.6.0.html).